# Degenerate Hilbert-Schmidt operators

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral, normed-spaces

Let us define a Hilbert Schmidt operator $A:L_2[a,b]\to L_2[a,b]$ by $$A\varphi:=\int_{[a,b]} K(s,t)\varphi(t)d\mu_t$$where $\mu_t$ is the linear Lebesgue measure. A *degenerate* case is represented by a $K$ having the form $\sum_{i=1}^n P_i(s)Q_i(t)$ where $\forall i=1,\ldots,n\quad P_i,Q_i\in L_2[a,b]$ and such $P_i, Q_i$ can be assumed to be linearly independent, without loss of generality. I read (p. 469 of Kolmogorov-Fomin's [here](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf)) that any operator $A$ is the limit of a succession of degenerate cases. How can it be proved? I thank you all very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(\phi_i)_i$ be an orthonormal basis of $L^2(a,b)$. Define the basis $(\Phi_{ij})_{i,j}$ of $L^2([a,b] \times [a,b])$ via tensor products, $\Phi_{ij}(s,t) = \phi_i(s) \phi_j(t)$. Now expand the kernel $K$ in this basis,
$$
K = \sum_{i,j} \alpha_{ij} \Phi_{ij}.
$$
Truncate the expansion and you have a degenerate approximation:
$$
K_N(s,t) = \sum_{i,j \le N} \alpha_{ij} \Phi_{ij}(s,t)
= \sum_{i,j \le N} \alpha_{ij} \phi_{i}(s)\phi_j(t) \, .
$$